# error when creating table

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

In my php program i want to check if table is exist or not. if table not exist want to create a table...

the code i've been tried

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['uniqueno']))
{
            $uniqueno=$_POST['uniqueno'];
            $user=$_SESSION['userid'];
            $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$user."'"))==1)
            { echo "table exists"; }
            else
            {
                $create=mysql_query("create table '$user'(  uniqueno varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                                                            elementno varchar(30),
                                                            name varchar(50),
                                                            process varchar(30),
                                                            date datetime(30), 
                                                            PRIMARY KEY (uniqueno) 
                                                          )");
                if(!$create)
                {
                    echo mysql_error();
                }                       
            }
}
?>
```

When i try this code displays following error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''sai'(  uniqueno varchar(10) NOT NULL, elementno varchar(30), ' at line 1 ".

thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$create=mysql_query("create table $user (  uniqueno varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                                                        elementno varchar(30),
                                                        name varchar(50),
                                                        process varchar(30),
                                                        date datetime, 
                                                        PRIMARY KEY (uniqueno) 
                                                      )");
```

- The single quote around $user is not needed.
- The field length is not needed for datetime field.

Answer (score 2):

Take out single quote for table name and the query should be something as

```
"create table $user(  uniqueno varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                      elementno varchar(30),
                      name varchar(50),
                      process varchar(30),
                      date datetime, 
                      PRIMARY KEY (uniqueno) 
                    )"
```

Comment: when using this query a another error messege shown :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(30), PRIMARY KEY (uniqueno) )' at line 5

Comment: Sorry I did not notice there is one more issue, datetime does not need a length so I updated the answer and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$create=mysql_query("create table $user (  uniqueno varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                                           elementno varchar(30),
                                           name varchar(50),
                                           process varchar(30),
                                           date datetime(30), 
                                           PRIMARY KEY (uniqueno) 
                                        )");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
//your db connection code here
if( isset($_POST['uniqueno']))
{
            $uniqueno=$_POST['uniqueno'];
            $userid=$_POST['userid'];
            $user=$_SESSION[$userid];
            $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$user."'"))==1)
            { echo "table exists"; }
            else
            {
                $create=mysql_query("create table ".$user."(`uniqueno` varchar(10) NOT NULL,`elementno` varchar(30),`name` varchar(50),`process` varchar(30),`date` datetime, PRIMARY KEY(`uniqueno`))");
                if(!$create)
                {
                    echo mysql_error();
                }                       
            }
}
?>
```